# TCP Server to communicate with Client on demand

Tags: python, python-3.x, tcp, python-asyncio

Is there a way to memorize all the client instances (in a dictionary for example), and send a message/communicate on demand to whichever client needed?

```
import asyncio

class EchoServerClientProtocol(asyncio.Protocol):
    def connection_made(self, transport):
        self.transport = transport
        self.peername = transport.get_extra_info('peername')
        
        print('Connection from {}'.format(self.peername))

    def data_received(self, data):
        message = data.decode()
        print('Data received: {!r}'.format(message))

        print('Send: {!r}'.format(message))
        self.transport.write(data)

    def connection_lost(self, exc):
        print('Lost connection of {}'.format(self.peername))
        self.transport.close()

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
coro = loop.create_server(EchoServerClientProtocol, '127.0.0.1', 8888)
server = loop.run_until_complete(coro)

print('Serving on {}'.format(server.sockets[0].getsockname()))
try:
    loop.run_forever()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass

server.close()
loop.run_until_complete(server.wait_closed())
loop.close()
```

Comment: this is Client-Server connection which expects that only client sends requests and server sends only answers on these requests. You try to replace server with client - your server want to send requests (like client) and client has to receive it (like server). In normal Client-Server you can't do this - and people use loop in client which periodicaly sends requests to server to ask if there are new messages. In web browser they start using `websockets` to send from server to client on demend. But it may need different modules then Client-Server

Comment: @furas This will be used to send json data to a receipt printer from a PY app, so can't use websockets. Running the loop on the client could be very taxing because the server would need to check a DB all the time. And it wont be instant. Instead of relying on a trigger notify from the DB and then sending the json.

Comment: then your client has to run as server and wait for request from your PY app which has to run as client.

Comment: @furas Will the "server" aka client be able to connect to multiple "servers" aka clients? Any examples?

Comment: BTW: loops in client works or works in all instant messagers which use HTTP for this.

Comment: @furas I'm not using HTTP. Connecting directly via socket.

Comment: example you (client) connect with many pages (servers) every day.

Comment: you show ClientServerProtocol so I though you use method client-server. But if you use socket and you can use whatever you like then your server and client can run bidirectional - they can send and receive at the same time. It may need to run it in separated thread (one for sending and other for receiving) because it may blocks. OR you would have to use module `select` to check if there is something to receive on socket before you start receiving.

Comment: @furas Do you know of any examples aka source code I could look at?

Comment: with two threads it looks like two conections Client-Server in two different directions. Maybe I have some example code on [GitHub/python-examples/socket](https://github.com/furas/python-examples/tree/master/socket) but I don't remeber. But rather I don't have version with [select](https://docs.python.org/3/library/select.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to be able to maintain a map of connections and then send data to the connections at a later time.

```py
import asyncio
from functools import partial
from random import choice, randint

class Echo(asyncio.Protocol):
    def __init__(self, client_map):
        self.client_map = client_map

    def connection_made(self, transport):
        self.transport = transport
        peername = transport.get_extra_info("peername")
        print(f"[x] connected to {peername}")
        self.client_map[transport.get_extra_info("peername")] = self

    def connection_lost(self, exc):
        peername = self.transport.get_extra_info("peername")
        print(f"[!] disconnected from {peername}")
        del self.client_map[peername]

    def data_received(self, data):
        print(f"<<< {data}")
        self.transport.write(b">>> " + data)

def protocol_factory(client_map):
    proto = Echo(client_map)
    return proto

def random_hello(loop, client_map):
    delay = randint(1, 10)
    if len(client_map) > 0:
        peername = choice(sorted(client_map))
        client_map[peername].transport.write(b">>> random hello\n")

    loop.call_later(
        delay, random_hello, loop, client_map,
    )

async def main():
    loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
    client_map = {}
    _protocol_factory = partial(protocol_factory, client_map=client_map)
    server = await loop.create_server(_protocol_factory, "127.0.0.1", 8888,)
    random_hello(loop, client_map)
    async with server:
        await server.serve_forever()

asyncio.run(main())
```

What makes this all work is `protocol_factory()`. You pass in a `client_map: dict`, which will then be a shared variable in all the protocol objects, and as clients connect, the protocol object will be stored under the `peername` key. The `random_hello()` function demonstrates sending data to a protocol. Pass in `client_map` anywhere you want to be able to access connected clients and send data over the network.